# Azure DevOps Pipeline with BitBucket repo - triggering build on any PR change not just code changes

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

We have a repository hosted in BitBucket with the build pipelines in Azure DevOps.

In the yaml file for the pipeline we have a pr trigger defined.

```
pr:
  - master
  - develop
  - release*
```

This is working as expected and triggering a new pipeline run when a PR to one of the specified branches is created. It also triggers a new build when the code in the PR branch is updated.

However, it also triggers a new build when any change is made to the PR - e.g. updating the PR description or adding a new reviewer. How do we prevent this? The code hasn't changed so we don't need a new build. And triggering a new build on every meta change to the PR is causing unnecessary builds and slowing development.

Edit: And weirdly it looks like it cancels the previous builds when a new one is triggered and then deletes the build once cancelling completes. Which causes even more confusion.

Comment: may i know if my answer helps? let me know if you have any queries, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up building a function app that we host in Azure to handle this. The function app exposed a function that we then called from BitBucket as a web hook. The function maintained a list of commit hashes that had been built for each branch. If the function received a call with a commit it hadn't seen before then it queued up a new build. If the function had seen the commit before then it didn't queue a build. This enabled us to only build the PR on new code changes.
[image]

This works well, however the downside is that when we queue the build it gets queued as a particular user and can't be queued on behalf of someone. This means that the build emails don't go to the correct user. To get around this we have each developer provide an Azure DevOps PAT with execute build permissions and we use the PAT for the relevant user when we queue the buld.

Answer (score 2):

It's a known limitation of the BitBucket integration with Azure DevOps Pipelines. You can check the doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/bitbucket?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#pr-triggers):

[image]

As a workaround, you can use a custom condition in your pipeline to check if the code has actually changed since the last build. You can use a script to compare the commit hashes of the **current** and **previous** builds, and set a variable to control the execution of the rest of the pipeline. Sample listed below.

For your 2nd query, you need to manually specify `autoCancel` for PR trigger as value `false`, as it's default as true.

[image]

Below is my sample to compare commit between pull request build(current) and previous build, hope it helpes.

```
# Starter pipeline
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml

trigger: none

variables:
  system.debug: true

pr:
  autoCancel: false
  branches:
    include:
     - master
     - dev*

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2019'

steps:
- bash: |
    # Get the commit hash of the current build
    currentCommit=$(System.PullRequest.SourceCommitId)
    echo "Current commit: $currentCommit"

    # Get the commit hash of the previous build
    previousCommit=$(az pipelines runs list --branch $(System.PullRequest.SourceBranch) --org $(System.CollectionUri) --project $(System.TeamProject) --pipeline-ids $(System.DefinitionId) --top 1 --query "[].sourceVersion" -o tsv)
    echo "Previous commit: $previousCommit"

    # Compare the commit hashes and set a variable
    if [ "$currentCommit" == "$previousCommit" ]; then
      echo "No code change detected, skipping the rest of the pipeline"
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=skipPipeline]true"
    else
      echo "Code change detected, running the rest of the pipeline"
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=skipPipeline]false"
    fi
  env:
    AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)
  name: checkCodeChange

- script: echo "This step will run only if there is a code change"
  condition: ne(variables['skipPipeline'], 'true')

- script: echo "This step will run only if there is NO code change"
  condition: eq(variables['skipPipeline'], 'true')
```

Below is the code change found：
[image]

And edit pull request(add description), no code found:

[image]

Comment: This approached works to an extent. But our pipeline is complicated and skipping every stage adds a lot of complexity with additional conditions. It also causes confusion with passed builds that aren't real and had edge cases with multiple builds queued at the same time. 
Therefore, we went with building our own web hook called from BitBucket that would queue the build in DevOps if the commit hadn't already been built for that branch. 
Would be so much better if this functionality just worked out of the box though.

Comment: Agree with you @MatthewvanBoheemen. As per DevOps doc, currently for  PR trigger of bitbucket has the limitation, hence it could be better to get the resolution from Bitbucket side instead.   In order to let others who have the similar question with you know how you resolved it more clearly, it's suggested that you can post an answer and [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) according to How does accepting an answer work. Thanks!